# Selenium: How to check if clicking a button directs to a new page or shows a pop up?

Tags: python, selenium, redirect

so I know how to check the URL of a button in selenium but I have a tricky situation here:

Let's say I click a button on the page [www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com). There are two outcomes (with no certainty of which one will happen):

1. The URL changes to [www.abc.com/newpage](http://www.abc.com/newpage) in the same tab
2. A pop-up shows up.

Is there a way I detect if clicking the button directs to abc.com/newpage or opens the pop-up in Selenium in Python?

Comment: you can just check what the url is after clicking the button, that should tell you what happened

Comment: so basically just rechecking the URL of the same tab? Like if it changes to abc.com/newpage or if it stays the same?

Comment: yep, it _should_ be as simple as that

Answer (score 1):

Here you can check both URL and pop up state:

```
if driver.current_url == "www.abc.com/newpage":
    print("redirected to new URL") 

try:
    driver.switch_to.alert
    print("pop up opened")
except:
    print("pop up not opened")
```